# Swift Combine, how to combine publishers and sink when only one publisher's value changes?

Tags: swift, combine

I have found ways of combining publishers using `MergeMany` or `CombineLatest`, but I don't seem to find a solution in my particular case.

Example:

```
class Test {
    @Published var firstNameValid: Bool = false
    @Published var lastNameValid: Bool = false
    @Published var emailValid: Bool = false

    @Published var allValid: Bool = false
}
```

I want `allValid` to become `false` when any of the previous publishers are set to `false`, and `true` if all of them are `true`.
I also don't want to hardcode the list of publishers I am observing since I want a flexible solution, so I want to be able to pass an array of `Bool` publishers to whatever code I use to do this.

I tried this

```
        let fieldPublishers = [$firstNameValid, $lastNameValid, $emailValid]
        Publishers
            .MergeMany(fieldPublishers)
            .sink { [weak self] values in
                self?.allValid = values.allSatisfy { $0 }
            }
            .store(in: &subscribers)
```

But this of course doesn't work because I get an array of publishers and not an array of values. I tried some other ways (forgot which ones) but they only seemed to call `sink` if I assigned a value during execution to all 3 publishers.

In the case of only using 2 publishers I managed to get it working using `CombineLatest`.

So the question is: Can I have `sink` triggered when only one of the publishers in an array changes value after instantiation of `Test`, and then iterate over the values of all the publishers I am observing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CombineLatest is indeed correct. You have three publishers so you would use CombineLatest3. In this example, I use CurrentValueSubject publishers instead of `@Published`, but it's the same principle:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let b1 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool,Never>(false)
    let b2 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool,Never>(false)
    let b3 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool,Never>(false)
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Publishers.CombineLatest3(b1,b2,b3)
            .map { [$0.0, $0.1, $0.2] }
            .map { $0.allSatisfy {$0}}
            .sink { print($0)}
            .store(in: &self.storage)
        
        // false
        delay(1) {
            self.b1.send(true) // false
            delay(1) {
                self.b2.send(true) // false
                delay(1) {
                    self.b3.send(true) // true
                    delay(1) {
                        self.b1.send(false) // false
                        delay(1) {
                            self.b1.send(true) // true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, now you may complain, that's okay for a hard-coded three publishers, but I want *any* number of publishers. Fine! Start with an array of your publishers, accumulate them one at a time with CombineLatest to form a publisher that produces an array of Bool:

```
    let list = [b1, b2, b3] // any number of them can go here!
    let pub = list.dropFirst().reduce(into: AnyPublisher(list[0].map{[$0]})) {
        res, b in
        res = res.combineLatest(b) {
            i1, i2 -> [Bool] in
            return i1 + [i2]
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    pub
        .map { $0.allSatisfy {$0}}
        .sink { print($0)}
        .store(in: &self.storage)
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much. I wrapped that into a slightly neater extension that others might find useful:

`extension Array where Element: Publisher {

    func combineAll() -> AnyPublisher<[Element.Output], Element.Failure>? {
        guard let first = first else { return nil }
        return dropFirst()
            .reduce(into: AnyPublisher(first.map { [$0] })) {
                $0 = $0.combineLatest($1) { $0 + [$1] }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
    }
}`

Comment: Note: The library [CombineExt](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt) provides an extension to a list adding a `combineLatest` function that does this more generally.

Comment: @tanzoniteblack That's totally awesome, thank you for mentioning it!

Answer (score -2):

This is technically not an answer to your last question but wouldn’t the property allValid make more sense as a computed property?

```
var allValid: Bool {
   firstNameValid && lastNameValid && emailValid
}
```

This would make sure, that allValid at all times represents the logical AND for the other three properties. I hope that I have understood the core of your question and this helped.

Comment: You can't subscribe to that property